# Why does bootstrap resize the button when I toggle to a spinner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, bootstrap-5

The button resizes whenever I toggle to a spinner and then toggle back to the button. I cannot figure out why.

```js
function update() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

  btn.innerHTML =
    '<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>';
  setTimeout(toDefault, 5000);

}

function toDefault() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
  btn.innerHTML =
    '<span class="btn btn-primary">Submit</span>';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar-nav">
  <button id='submitBtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick='update();'>Submit</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a button inside another button. Remove `btn btn-primary` from the span inside the block button.

```
function toDefault() {
    const btn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
    btn.innerHTML = '<span>Submit</span>';
}
```

Comment: This worked. 

  function buttonToDefault(){
        const btn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
        btn.innerHTML =
            '<span>Submit</span>';
    }

Answer (score 0):

Because of

```
btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(38 143 255 / 50%);
}
```

So if you want to override those,

```
btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

You might need a parent selector before those to make it prioritize your rule.